# Android get JSON Array from phone storage

Tags: java, android, json

I have a .json file in a directory within phone storage. I want to get JsonArray from it.

There is already one way which is buffer string line by line and make it complete string with StringBuilder and then parse with the JSON class.

I wonder if there is a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parsing JSON is better (faster and simple) to use GSON or Jackson libraries. If you look for them on internet, there are a lot reviews about which is faster.

I prefer to use GSON.

Ok, to use one of these libraries is going to improve the "parsing" process.

Thinking about how we could improve the operations to open the file, read line by line, etc...

Take one look to these methods/object of the GSON library, are able to parsing directly from a local file.  "JsonReader" Object !!!

[Gson Streaming To Read And Write JSON](http://www.mkyong.com/java/gson-streaming-to-read-and-write-json/)